# Send-email to an email of a Custom Object (not a Contact's email)

Tags: apex, email, email-template, url

I am on an Account page. I put a "Send email to External Agent" button. Behind this button there is a page connected to a controller:

`public with sharing class emailToAgenteEsterno{
    public Case c;
    public Case c_1 {get;set;}
    public EmailTemplate emailt1;

    public Account acc;
    public Agente_Esterno__c ae;
    public Contact cont;`

```
public emailToAgenteEsterno(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    c = ( Case )controller.getRecord();
    c_1=[SELECT Id, Account.Agente_Esterno__c, Account.Agente_Esterno__r.Email__c, AccountId, CaseNumber  
         FROM Case 
         WHERE Id=:c.Id];

    emailt1=[SELECT Id 
             FROM EmailTemplate 
             WHERE Name='Inoltro case per Agente Esterno' ];        

    cont = [SELECT Id, email 
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE   AccountId =: c_1.AccountId
                AND Agente_Esterno__c = true];

}

    public pageReference returntopage(){

       return new PageReference('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=003&p2_lkid='+cont.id+'&p3_lkid='+c_1.Id+'&retURL='+c_1.Id+'&p5=&template_id='+emailt1.Id+'');

    }
```

}

In the method **returntopage()** there is a "way" in which Salesforce create a template putting the contact (**cont.id**) email in the TO of the mail. At its place I need to put another email (Account.Agente_Esterno__r.**Email__c**). I think I cannot use that URL because instead of the contact Id I should put the id of the Object containing the email I need (Agente_Esterno__c).

Summarizing:
I have an **email template** and an **email**. Clicking the button *"Send email to External Agent"* I'd like to go on a page with that email template and with the field "to" filled with that email. What should I do?

Comment: You are basically doing URL hacking, you will have to find itself it that URL support custom object or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the email you need to send to as a string with SOQL and then use it in the URL "p24" parameter that controls the "additional to" field.

I.e. https://eu5.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p24=email@agent.com

Comment: I know that I shoudn't use the comment line to say thanks but.... THANKS THANKS THANKS!!!

Comment: @AndreaIanni௫ Here is a complete list of parameters which can be sent through the URL                                                                                     `p3_lkid – Related To
retURL – Return URL if cancel is pressed
p2_lkid – To (Contact or Lead ID)
p4 – CC
p5 – BCC
p6 – Subject
p23- Email Body
p24 – Additional To
template_id – Salesforce Email Template ID`                                                       Source - http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-email-url-hack-tutorial/